# Flutter/Dart - Print output of all child processes to stdout

Tags: flutter, dart, process, stdout, common-workflow-language

I am developing a Flutter desktop app, which at some point runs a `Process`. For this process I want to read the output and do things in Flutter according to it. The problem I am having is that not all output gets is shown via `process.stdout`, namely some `INFO` logs I would want to read as well.

Here's the (very simple) code:

```
Process process = await Process.start(
    "cwltool",
    [
        "--verbose",
        "Oesophageal-varices.cwl",
        "Oesophageal-varices-inputs.yml"
    ],
);

await process.stdout
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .forEach(print)
```

With this, the output is only:

```
{
    "cases": {
        "location": "file:///somelocation/oesophageal-varices-cases.csv",
        "basename": "oesophageal-varices-cases.csv",
        "class": "File",
        "checksum": "sha1$0b3f04bbeaac24499166fd56d93ad8bd6acb9ca8",
        "size": 670,
        "path": "/somelocation/oesophageal-varices-cases.csv"
    }
}
```

But when I run the same process in terminal, it also prints `INFO` logs, which I would desperately need in Flutter. I suspect the logging done by a python child process underneath is not passed on to `process.stdout`, hence them not printing.

How would I go about accessing the `INFO` logs too using Dart?

Comment: oh my, that is exactly where they go. super weird. thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) commented, interestingly enough the logs are going to `process.stderr`.

Comment: The comment was on this question, I tagged the user profile.

Comment: sorry, didn't understand at the time.